# 3D animated show with 4 kids, 3 boys and 1 girl

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, animation

There was a show that was 3D animated, i believe on Cartoon Network, that featured 4 kids w/ 3 boys and 1 girl. All I can remember is that the girl wore pink and might’ve had a low brown ponytail?

The kids were superhero’s or at least helping people around, but I’m not sure on that

There was a specific episode where the girl’s crush got sick and fell in love with her

Any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, when did you watch this show? How old were the kids? Were they all the same ages? What were their superpowers? What was the setting? What were their names? Did they fight a villain? Why was the girl hanging around with the boys (relative/friend)? Were any of them related to each other? Did they have a pet or sidekick? Did they have any gadgets? What was the animation-style?

Comment: What do you mean by 3D animated?

Comment: If only they said they were dogs then I'd probably recognise it...

Comment: Did the kids have any super powers? If so, what kind? If not, were there any other science fiction or fantasy elements in this show?

Comment: @Ragnarok - 3D animation refers to 3D computer-generated models, like in _Toy Story_.